# Tkinter 'Entry' object is not callable

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I am getting error with a button that I created. My code is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)

#funcion para agregar datos nuevos
def agregarDato(fecha,campo,labor,tipoGasto,monto,loggedBy,detalle):
   dato=[fecha,campo,labor,tipoGasto,monto,loggedBy,detalle]
   mesAno=fecha.split('/')[1]+'-'+fecha.split('/')[2]
   #si el archivo mes-ano existe entonces se edita. Si no, se crea y agrega
   archivo=open(mesAno+'.txt', 'a')
   archivo.write(str(dato)+'\n')




leftFrame=Frame(root, width=500,height=300)
leftFrame.pack(side=LEFT)
rightFrame=Frame(root, width=500,height=300)
rightFrame.pack()
### Texto y cajas
label_fecha=Label(leftFrame,text='Fecha:')
label_campo=Label(leftFrame,text='Campo:')
label_labor=Label(leftFrame,text='Labor:')
label_tipoGasto=Label(rightFrame,text='Tipo de gasto:')
label_monto=Label(rightFrame,text='Monto:')
label_detalle=Label(rightFrame,text='Detalle:')
label_loggedBy=Label(leftFrame,text='Autor:')

entry_fecha=Entry(leftFrame)
entry_campo=Entry(leftFrame)
entry_labor=Entry(leftFrame)
entry_tipoGasto=Entry(rightFrame)
entry_monto=Entry(rightFrame)
entry_detalle=Entry(rightFrame)
entry_loggedBy=Entry(leftFrame)

label_fecha.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=E)
label_campo.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=E)
label_labor.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=E)
label_tipoGasto.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=E)
label_monto.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=E)
label_detalle.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=E)
label_loggedBy.grid(row=3,column=0,sticky=E)

entry_fecha.grid(row=0,column=1)
entry_campo.grid(row=1,column=1)
entry_labor.grid(row=2,column=1)
entry_tipoGasto.grid(row=0,column=1)
entry_monto.grid(row=1,column=1)
entry_detalle.grid(row=2,column=1)
entry_loggedBy.grid(row=3,column=1)

###botones ingresar y volver
boton_ingresar=Button(rightFrame,text='Ingresar',command= lambda: agregarDato(entry_fecha.get(),entry_campo.get,entry_labor.get(),entry_tipoGasto(),entry_monto.get(),entry_loggedBy.get(),entry_detalle.get()))
boton_ingresar.grid(row=3,column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

The error that I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1487, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Matias\Desktop\Proyecto MiPi\Int_pagAgregarDato.py", line 56, in <lambda>
    boton_ingresar=Button(rightFrame,text='Ingresar',command= lambda: agregarDato(entry_fecha.get(),entry_campo.get(),entry_labor.get(),entry_tipoGasto(),entry_monto.get(),entry_loggedBy.get(),entry_detalle.get()))
TypeError: 'Entry' object is not callable
```

Comment: Could you cut this down to a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

In the line that is identified by the error code, you have this:

```
boton_ingresar=Button(..., entry_tipoGasto(),...)
```

Notice how you are trying to call the entry (as the error message states), rather than calling the `get` method on the entry.

Change the code to be `...entry_tipoGastro.get()...`

Comment: @matnagra: this is a good example of why `lambda` should be avoided: if each of those calls to `get()` we're on a separate line the error message would have done a better job of pinpointing the error.

Comment: but how do I make a button that does the same thing without using it?
I could´t find a better example than using lambda and to be honest I don´t really like that command...

Comment: @matnagra: Since you create variables in the global namespace, they are available everywhere. So, just call `entry_tipoGastro.get()` inside the function called by the button.

Comment: You are right... that actually is a better idea.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of your button you put:

```
entry_tipoGasto()
```

instead of

```
entry_tipoGasto.get()
```

so you try to call an entry